# How can I check if a select field has been used with states?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form where I'd like to hide a fieldset until the user has used a select (which option doesn't matter).

So far I've the following code:

```
$form['location'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $locations,
  '#required' => true,
);

$form['uploads'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => 'Foobar',
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      'select[name="location"]' => array('empty' => false)
    )
  )
);
```

Apparently *empty*, *checked*, *filled* don't do the trick. If I check for one specific value with the following code works.

```
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    'select[name="location"]' => array('value' => 'foo')
  )
)
```

But what would be the solution for the check if *any value* has been selected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't tried it but a simple negate on an empty string might work:

```
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    'select[name="location"]' => array('!value' => '')
  )
)
```

Comment: I have tried it: it works.

Comment: If you're using `drupal_map_assoc()`, be careful you aren't accidentally changing the empty string value `''` to something else.

Comment: Got it working with `['!value' => '_none']`